# Disjunction and conjunction in modal logic

Tags: modal-logic

Is there a system of modal logic in which

$\Box (A\vee B)\leftrightarrow\Box A\vee\Box B$,

$\Box (A\wedge B)\leftrightarrow\Box A\wedge\Box B$,

$\Diamond (A\vee B)\leftrightarrow\Diamond A\vee\Diamond B$,

$\Diamond (A\wedge B)\leftrightarrow\Diamond A\wedge\Diamond B$

hold?

Alternatively, is there a modal system in which

$\Box (A\vee B)\leftrightarrow\Box A\vee\Box B$

and

$\Diamond (A\wedge B)\leftrightarrow\Diamond A\wedge\Diamond B$?

are theorems?

Answer (score 3):

A quick comment - such systems correspond to a very narrow class of [Kripke frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics).

Think about the formula "$\Box(A\vee \neg A)$." This is a tautology in most modal systems, and so by the rule "$\Box(A\vee B)\iff\Box A\vee\Box B$", a system with your property would satisfy "$\Box A\vee\Box \neg A$" for all sentences $A$.

From this, it's easy to that the Kripke frames satisfying this rule are exactly those in which every world sees exactly one world (possibly itself). In particular, assuming rule "$T$" ($\Box A\implies A$), we have $\Box A\iff A$ and so the modalities trivialize.

Comment: Huh I would not call the $T$-axiom *mild*. Take into account that in PA assuming $Bew(A)\rightarrow A$ makes the logic inconsistent.

Comment: @Jsevillamol That's a very good point - quite silly of me! I almost always work with reflexive frames, where $T$ trivially holds, but of course things get much more interesting if we look at provability-type logics. I've edited my answer to not be nonsense.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Are you able to provide a literature reference for such Kripke frames and this class of axioms?

Answer (score 0):

In a system of modal logic based on Lukasiewicz 3-valued logic, these are all theorems.

Lp corresponds to $\Box$p

Mp corresponds to $\Diamond$p

In this system, $\Box$ (p $\lor$~p) is *not* a theorem. It is a statement of the law of bivalence, which does not generally hold in L3. It can be regarded as a contingent statement, applicable to some but not all statements. This version of modal logic also requires that one swallow the existence of propositions for which $\Diamond$(p $\land$ ~p).